# 'Associate App with the store' option is not showing is visual studio ultimate 2013 for windows phone 8.1 silverlight project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-store-apps

I need to publish my `windows phone 8.1 silverlight` application to the store.
I used `Visual Studio 2013  Ultimate` for developing the application.

But I could not find '`Associate App with the store`' option in the `project` tab.
`Lauch app certification kit` is the only available option . How do I associate app with the store ?
Please help.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight apps don't need to be manually associated with the store. The application ID, etc. will be set automatically on the xap when it is uploaded and signed.

For a Windows Runtime app the "Associate the app with the store" menu will copy the application ID, publisher ID, etc. locally into the appxmanifest.

Comment: I need to test push notification using wns. In windows phone 8.1 xamp app it is possible by just associate app to the store. What about this case ? I sit possible to test it by manually adding the details to the package file ?

Answer (score 1):

Only universal phone app can be associated with the store to be able to [bundle it with Windows Store app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206733(v=vs.105).aspx) into one package. It's useless for silverlight apps.

Comment: Associated with the store and associated with other apps in the store are different things. You can associate a Windows Phone Silverlight app with a Windows Store app, but that's not what asitis is talking about. Associating the apps with each other is done purely on the dashboard, not in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should select:
"Store" -> "Create app package" and follow the steps there.

Here you can find more information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx

Comment: This option is not available .

Comment: Create app package is for Windows Runtime apps. Silverlight apps upload the xap file created by the normal build process.